# Convert linux sha512 shadow to hex

Tags: python, linux, encryption, hash, sha512

I am trying to understand the linux shadow string format, and convert the string to a general hex format, just like how MD5 is usually represented.

I was following the definitions here
http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt

As described, the final step (step 22) is a special base-64 encoding, with re-ordered bytes.

I wrote a python script(my first python program) to decode the base64 then put it back to the original order.

But **THE PROBLEM IS**, the result is not the same string as usual SHA1 hashes.

For example, a password "123" (without quotes) with salt "456" will produce a shadow string

> $6$456$yTSeWYNbvZDCsuZIN.Qdeg.0DxY5N1XddpO7qgFqjnZOqpy5QXIeMM7pdQYWIgu6Y3pSh5eYqJ21fqrlrjhJe/

With my program, it generates

> A922F952190B1ED9ADD9EFEDA918472364A10CABDBE79D7B5EA52A4FA6691B6A7648D429AB7BED45C7F7FE9938B8C0084F3025365C1FDC968A145192767D566A

However the SHA512 hash of 123456 and 456123 are

> BA3253876AED6BC22D4A6FF53D8406C6AD864195ED144AB5C87621B6C233B548BAEAE6956DF346EC8C17F5EA10F35EE3CBC514797ED7DDD3145464E2A0BAB413
>
> CA3D1DDE02C4B15D2E95521E259C5E08AAEA8FEAA722BA14014605249EFE3F248DB3D98AA7C4ACCBE887E1B40573D7EBA71017C5DF029C16C8D6F06B0FFDA310

None of them is the same as my result. So, is there anything I understood wrong about the shadow generation method? Or something wrong with my code?

my python code (input should be the base64 code, i.e. the string after the last "$" of a shadow string):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# filename: conv.py
import sys
b64s = "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
bm = ( \
        (0,21,42), \
        (22,43,1), \
        (44,2,23), \
        (3,24,45), \
        (25,46,4), \
        (47,5,26), \
        (6,27,48), \
        (28,49,7), \
        (50,8,29), \
        (9,30,51), \
        (31,52,10), \
        (53,11,32), \
        (12,33,54), \
        (34,55,13), \
        (56,14,35), \
        (15,36,57), \
        (37,58,16), \
        (59,17,38), \
        (18,39,60), \
        (40,61,19), \
        (62,20,41), \
        ('*','*',63))

sd_str = raw_input('Enter a Shadow String: ')
ba = [0]*64
ba_org = [0]*64
for i in range (0,21):
        byte24 = 0
        for j in range(0,4):
                byte24 += (b64s.find(sd_str[i*4+j]) << (j*6))

        for j in range(0,3):
                ba[bm[i][2-j]] = ((byte24>>(j*8))&0x0000FF)

byte24 = b64s.find(sd_str[84]) + (b64s.find(sd_str[85])<<6)
ba[63] = byte24        #last byte
for i in range (0,64):
        sys.stdout.write('%02X' % ba[i])

sys.stdout.write('\n')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest thing you're missing is that the password hash in the shadow file is iterated. The hash value for the password `123` is not `sha(password + salt)`, it's `sha(sha(sha(sha(password + salt) + salt) + salt)...)`, with 5000 levels of nesting by default.

Comment: Thank you duskwuff. I thought if it is repeatedly hashed, the number of levels should be represent as round in the beginning of the salt string, i.e. "rounds=5000$"

Comment: If the round count isn't specified, it defaults to 5000.

Comment: Confirmed, crypt.crypt("123","$6$rounds=5000$456$") == crypt.crypt("123","$6$456$"). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The "sha256_crypt" algorithm is not just an SHA256 hash - it's rather complicated construction all it's own, which happens to use SHA256 as a cryptographic primitive, hence the name.

Not only does the rounds value require multiple compositions of the SHA256 function, it's not even `sha256(sha256(...))`, but a much more complicated loop, with a number of additional setup steps beforehand... the goal of which is to make it much more suitable for password hashing than simply `sha256()`. That said, the transposition before encoding to base64, and the custom base64 encoding, doesn't really add anything security-wise, it just makes more of a pain to implement.

I'd suggest reading the rest of the Akkdia.org document, which describes exactly how the shadow hash is calculated. Alternately, you can look at [sha2_crypt.py](https://code.google.com/p/passlib/source/browse/passlib/handlers/sha2_crypt.py?name=1.5.3) in the source of the Passlib project, which shows what you need to implement - look for the `raw_sha256_crypt()` function, that's the right starting point, though the meat is in `raw_sha_crypt()`. Note that I linked you to the v1.5.3 source, because the [latest version](https://code.google.com/p/passlib/source/browse/passlib/handlers/sha2_crypt.py?name=1.6.1) (while faster) is also a bit harder to understand.